# What is the formula for Fourier series on the unit disk?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Wikipedia gives a formula for two dimensional Fourier series on a square of length 2pi.[image]

If I want to approximate functions on the unit disk do I just change the integration area from the square to the disk ?

Comment: A yes would suffice, but a no needs elaboration :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your formula would not work just by changing the domain of integration. In the same vein there is another useful basin given by the [Fourier Bessel series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier%E2%80%93Bessel_series). The idea is to go in polar coordinates and diagonalise the Laplacian by separation of variables. You write:
$$
f(r,\phi) = \sum_{m,n\in\mathbb N^2} c_{mn}e^{im\phi}J_m(u_{mn}r)
$$
with $u_{mn}$ the $n$th root of $J_m$. You can calculate the coefficients with:
$$
c_{mn} = \frac{1}{\pi J_{m+1}(u_{mn})}\int_0^{+\infty}rdr\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi e^{-im\phi}J_m(u_{mn}r)f(r,\phi)
$$

You can check that the basis functions $e_{mn}=e^{im\phi}J_m(u_{mn}r)$ are orthogonal and are eigenvectors of the Laplacian:
$$\Delta=\partial_r^2+\frac{1}{r}\partial_r+\frac{1}{r^2}\partial_\phi^2$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will be able to figure this out now.